# How do you alias the 'yo' of yeoman with a custom name

Tags: angularjs, npm, yeoman

I want to alias

```
$ yo directive myDirective
```

To be something like this:

```
$ awesomeness directive myDirective
```

How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your ~/.bashrc

```
alias awesomeness='yo'
```

Comment: Well, i'd have to do this for every user of 'awesomeness'

Comment: I'd prefer a way that would instantly work after npm installing my framework